# numpy data slicing with mixed type

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I use numpy.genfromtxt to load data from a csv file, and this file has mixed data type, like the following:

```
date,value1,value2
1997-02, 432, 1
1997-03, 300, 1
1997-04, 432, 0
```

I use the following command to load data:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('data/test.csv', dtype=None, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
```

and I get

```
array([(b'1997-02', 432, 1), (b'1997-03', 300, 1), (b'1997-04', 432, 0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S7'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8')])
```

Now I want only the date of this data, how can I slice the numpy array with mixed type? I tried to use data[:,0] but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the field name:

```
data['f0']

# array([b'1997-02', b'1997-03', b'1997-04'], 
#       dtype='|S7')
```

---

And further for your reading purpose, I think you want to specify the `names = True` instead of `skip_header` so that the first line will be read in as the field names of the structured array:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('data/test.csv', dtype=None, delimiter=',', names = True)
​    
data
# array([(b'1997-02', 432, 1), (b'1997-03', 300, 1), (b'1997-04', 432, 0)], 
#       dtype=[('date', 'S7'), ('value1', '<i8'), ('value2', '<i8')])
```

Now you can access `date` as:

```
data['date']
# array([b'1997-02', b'1997-03', b'1997-04'], 
#       dtype='|S7')
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dtype=None` it deduces field dtypes, in this case one strings, the rest integers.  You can refine the dtype with a `np.datetime64` definition ('M' for months)

```
In [419]: dt = ['datetime64[M]', 'i', 'i']
In [420]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=dt)
In [421]: data
Out[421]: 
array([('1997-02', 432, 1), 
       ('1997-03', 300, 1), 
       ('1997-04', 432, 0)], 
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[M]'), ('value1', '<i4'), ('value2', '<i4')])
```

This a 1d structured array with shape (3,).  Instead of columns it has named `fields`, which are accessed by name rather than index.

```
In [422]: data['date']
Out[422]: array(['1997-02', '1997-03', '1997-04'], dtype='datetime64[M]')
```

Stick with the default if you'd rather work with the string. But it's easy to convert the datetime objects to things

days:

```
In [424]: data['date'].astype('datetime64[D]')
Out[424]: array(['1997-02-01', '1997-03-01', '1997-04-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

strings

```
In [427]: data['date'].astype('U7')
Out[427]: 
array(['1997-02', '1997-03', '1997-04'], 
      dtype='<U7')
```

`datetime` objects:

```
In [428]: data['date'].tolist()
Out[428]: 
[datetime.date(1997, 2, 1),
 datetime.date(1997, 3, 1),
 datetime.date(1997, 4, 1)]
```

integers:

```
In [429]: data['date'].astype(int)
Out[429]: array([325, 326, 327])
```